# Unknown Member Error

Tags: c#, android, xml, mono, xamarin.android

I'm working on an application for the Android OS using Android Mono so I can program it in C#.  All things are working well except for this one issue I am getting.

Basically, I have a sample code that changes the text of a button on every click.  I tried to modify the sample code so that instead of changing the button, it changes the text of an xml textview object and, upon getting this error, I replaced it with an edittext object.  I replaced it because it seemed common sense that editing an edittext would be easier than a textview.

Anywho,  I got the same error at the same place.  Whenever I try to change the textview.text or the edittext.text, the program freezes up and I get the error 'Unknown Member".

Here is the C# portion of the code:

```
Button ampButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.CurrentButton);
ampButton.Click += delegate
{
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.AmpScreen);
Button ampButton2 = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.CurrentButtonamp);
EditText ampData = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.ampdata);
ampButton2.Click += delegate
{
ampButton2.Text = string.Format("{0} clicks!", count2++);
ampData.Text = ampButton2.Text;
//string temp = Convert.ToString(count2) + " clicks!";
//ampData.Text=temp;
//count2++;
};
};
```

Here are the XML sections that are affected:
From the Main.xml:

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/CurrentButton"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/Amp"
/>
```

From the AmpScreen.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>  
<ImageView id="@+id/ampImage"
android:layout_width="50px"
android:layout_height="50px"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/amp"/>
<EditText id="@+id/ampdata"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Loading"/>
<Button
android:id="@+id/CurrentButtonamp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Re-scan"
/>
<Button
android:id="@+id/homeButtonamp"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Back"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a simple issue with your xml.

In your AmpScreen.xml on the EditText element:

```
id="@+id/ampdata"
```

should be:

```
android:id="@+id/ampdata"
```